# Haskell - Non-exhaustive patterns in my function

Tags: haskell, recursion, exception, functional-programming

I want to make a function that selects the given indexed elements from a list.

For example:

```
reconstruct' [1,4] "bear" = [br]
reconstruct' [2,3,4] [1,2,3,4,5] = [2,3,4]
```

Function definition:

```
reconstruct' :: [Int] -> [a] -> [a]
reconstruct' _ [] = []
reconstruct' (x:xs) l = [place (x-1) l ] ++ (reconstruct' (xs) l)

place :: Int -> [a] -> a
place _ [] = error "error"
place y (x:xs)  | y <= 0 = x
                 | otherwise = place (y-1) xs
```

My function is almost working, however after giving back the right elements, instead of closing the list it gives an error:
[2,3,4*** Exception: Non-exhaustive patterns in function reconstruct'

How could i fix this?

Comment: As you are juste prepending one element, you could simplify to: `reconstruct' (x:xs) l = (place (x-1) l )  :  (reconstruct' (xs) l)`

Comment: If you compile with warnings turned on (`-Wall`), GHC should warn you and list the missing case(s). It's very useful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not capturing the situation when the list of indices is empty:

```
reconstruct' [] _ = []
```